# square root in solidity

Tags: solidity, ether

I read here:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html

that...

> If any of the two is fractional, bit operations are disallowed and exponentiation is disallowed if the exponent is fractional (because that might result in a non-rational number).

Is there a workaround?

I am trying to achieve this:

```
minerFeeReward += totalSupply**0.5;
```